# What kind of caulk should I use around my bathtub?

Tags: caulking, bathroom

I would like to recaulk between the bathtub and the ceramic-tile wall, but there are many kinds of caulking for sale.  What kind should I use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I *just* caulked my shower last night. I used [GE Silicone II](http://www.caulkyourhome.com/ge-silicone-II-kitchen-and-bath.php) caulk from Home Depot. I read up on this a little before picking out what kind I needed. From what I can tell, silicone caulk is good for bathrooms because:

- It's permanently waterproof
- It doesn't crack or shrink

Another factor which may play into your choice of caulk could be whether or not it's paintable, but the most important factor for a bathroom is going to be waterproof/mold proof.

Comment: For some reason, the allegedly "mold-proof" GE Silicone II has caught red/black mold with me. I guess it could be because I hadn't eradicated the existing mold before re-caulking...

Comment: I had some black mold on caulk that wasn't smoothed.  I think the water was pooling up on it.

Comment: I had that problem with the GE Silicon II, and it had been properly smoothed. The caulk also seemed to discolor from clear to yellowish (on the wall, not in the tube) after a while.

Answer (score 6):

I just bought a permanent silicone product by GE which is guaranteed to dry in 1 hour and is mold resistant.

[GE 9.8 oz. White KB Supreme Silicone II Caulk](http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1vZ1xge/R-100669748/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053)

Comment: one thing to note: Make sure you smooth it out with a wet cloth as soon as you apply it. It will dry very very quickly.

Comment: I agree with @NTulip -- The biggest problem you will have is making it look nice.

Comment: Use all-purpose spray and wipe cleaner after application. Works wonders.

Answer (score 3):

I own a remodeling firm, and this is one of those things that so many get wrong and the manufacturers don't tell you how to get right.  There are 3 aspects homeowners never hear:
1.  All the old caulk HAS to come off.  Squeaky clean.
2.  All surfaces and substrates to be caulked need to be dry.  Bone dry.
3.  Use silicone if you must, but silicone or acrylic, the caulk will need to be redone in 2,3 or 4 years, no longer.  It just won't last longer.

The dirty secret about silicone is that *nothing* sticks to cured silicone caulk -- including new silicone caulk.  The old silicone has to be completely cleaned off.  This usually requires a single-edge razor blade and mineral spirits, followed by an alcohol wipe, followed by a wipe-down with bleach (chlorine or oxygen bleach - the latter being our preference).  The last two steps get what the first doesn't; the bleach being very important to kill mold where new caulk is to go.  Acrylic caulk, unless it's super hard, is generally much easier to clean-off than silicone.

THEN, before re-caulking, the surface needs to be dry.  Bone dry.  It really should stand for a day without being used before it's caulked.

As said, use silicone or acrylic, but assume you're going to be re-doing it in 2-4 years, so, for my nickel, I'd rather save my knuckles and knees and use acrylic caulk than crouch in a tub for an hour plus trying to remove all the silicone.  Either way, the tub/shower should not be used for another 24 hours.

Do all the above, and you'll have a great finished product -- that will last 2-4 years.  Skip a step, and you'll likely find something turning red or black in a matter of days or weeks.

A thorough, well-written article -- with step-by-step detail can be found here:  http://www.acmehowto.com/home-maintenance/general/caulk-tub-shower.php

Wish I had better news, but experience has taught us all the above.  Good luck.

Comment: As a follow-on, a well-detailed write-up on the procedure can be found here:

Comment: You write well, and it sounds like you speak from experience, (and with an air of authority); but it has been my humble experience that silicone typically lasts twice as long as acrylic caulk (for keeping a water tight seal).

Comment: True:  perhaps 4 years vs. 2 for acrylic?  Again, were it not for the cleanup effort required, silicone would be the clear choice.

Comment: I don't mean to sound enthusiastic or anything, but I would say 4-5 years for acrylic and 8-10 for silicone. Being able to put-off a chore for an extra 4-5 years is perhaps worth the extra effort (although it's not much effort if you ask me). I suppose it's debatable or relative to the individual, so my parting thought on this, is that life is all a matter of time.

Comment: Good info.  I have found it all to be true.  I use caulk, just b/c of the ease of re-doing vs silicone.  I have found a great solution in the shower to "renew" mildewed sealant.  Mix up a batch of bleach and baking soda, then paint it on thick.  Cover it with saran wrap to slow evaporation and spray bleach on the wall to allow it to re saturate the mixture every few hours.  Works amazingly.