# Tub re-glazed and re-caulked, drippy residue from caulking

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub, caulking

I recently had my bathtub re-glazed and re-caulked by a company that specializes in this.  The tub was re-caulked 3 days after it was re-glazed by the specialist.  Everything looked ok.  We waited about 30 hours until we used the shower after it was re-caulked (the person who did it said "24 hours").  Now I am noticing a drippy residue (which appears to be the caulking) where the caulking was applied.  What went wrong here and what can I do?
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: A picture might be helpful here.

Comment: @Tester101 - I will add a picture later tonight, thanks.

Comment: @Tester101 - Added pictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this happen just once before - a caulk that never seemed to cure. It just stayed runny, even when given multiple days to do so at room temperature. My guess is the caulk was old or stored under conditions that caused it to fail to cure, or perhaps it was simply a bad batch from the manufacturer. Regardless of the reason, clean it out, and redo the caulking job.

Comment: I agree. I'd try GE Silicone II caulk for the replacement. See http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2/caulking-around-the-bathtub and http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/35/is-there-a-trick-to-applying-caulk-using-a-caulk-gun